# Xamarin Cursor automatically created when page is popped up

Tags: xamarin.android

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pFB0h.gif)

Click on the options page and it will pop up.
Within the strike page there are several controls.
I always want the scroll to go to the top. But strangely, the cursor appears on the last TextEdit and the scroll seems to move there. Trying scrolltoasync on scrollview doesn't solve the problem. What should I do in this case?

Comment: So it automatically focuses the last EditText? Can i see your XML?

Comment: Could you please show some relevant code?

Comment: I entered the relevant code as an answer.

Comment: Did you use any third party nuget to display the popup?